# How can I discover the current LDAP structure?

Tags: mocking, ldap

I am working on a web application at the moment and I want to mock the ldap server it uses for authentication for testing purposes (so we don't use real ldap login credentials). But I am having difficulties with finding the structure of the current ldap server, so I can later immitate it in the mock ldap server (for which I already found a python solution). Is there a way to find out its structure/ hierrarchy? The code I have in store is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a LDAP Browser.

[Apache Studio](https://directory.apache.org/studio/) is my favorite.